# Core data problems on real device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I had a problem in my simulator - when I want to edit the table in core data or create a new table the program which was using the database fails every time I start it. So I google the problem and I found the solution - every time I want to change something in my tables I have to manually delete my database. So it works fine but nowadays I get the license for testing it on real device, but I do not know how will it works on real device. I work for company and maybe the database will be expanding with some new tables, and I really do not know how to prevent it in real device. I admit it is a strange problem, but can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your change your Core Data model during testing, you can easily delete your app from the simulator/device. In this case Xcode will install a new database on your simulator/device when you re-install the app and your app won't crash.

If the app has already been released in iTunes and you want to change the database, you have to implement [data migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html) in your app.

Hope I understood your question right. Please ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: HI can You help me whit another my problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954813/coredata-deleting-from-database-and-making-request  thx