# Check if database is empty in iOS without of calling current NSManagedObjectContext (Core Data)?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

[My question is similar to the following one but has differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956905/core-data-database-is-empty-test)

I use Core Data. The problem is if I use the current `NSManagedObjectContext` then I may get an incorrect result. For example:

1. From the beginning the db is filled.
2. My app deletes all the entities via the current context.
3. I get check if db filled and get `NO` but in reality the db is still filled because the context should be saved to apply the changes.

And example of my solution:

```
- (BOOL)isDBFilled {

    //separate context to
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease];
    [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:... inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setFetchLimit:1];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!results) {

        LOG(@"Fetch error: %@", error);
        abort();
    }
    if ([results count] == 0) {

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

So is it normal and safe to create another context just to check if db is filled? Or Is there better ways to perform this checking except of creating a separate `BOOL` variable which will be changed before db changes and after them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine to use a separate context to check if the database is populated or not. The overhead is minimal, so I would have no objections.

Please note that Apple does not necessarily agree. From the "Core Data Snippets":

> Neither should a view controller create a context for its own use (unless it’s a nested context).

That being said, I do not see the need for this. If you delete all entities, save and then check should get an empty database. If you delete all entities and do not save and then check, you should get a non-empty database. You can easily - and more easily - do this with one context.

PS: `autorelease` seems to indicate that you are using a very old SDK. How about upgrading?

Comment: `autorelease` doesn't mean an old sdk. It means the ARC is disabled manually. And I don't agree with your proposal to save the context twice: 1)I can't always determine when I want to check if db is filled; 2)context saving takes enough long time so it should be called as less times as possible

Comment: You are confusing the deletion of all records and saving - which could take a long time - and the checking of the db (which should take next to no time). I you cannot determine when you want to check, there is some flaw in the logic of your application. (Also, this would be another question.) My answer stands: you can use a separate context, but should not.

Comment: it is not a flaw. It is because of changing of customer's requirements.